# UITableViewController within UIContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a static UITableViewController embedded within a UIContainerView. All created using Storyboards.

I'm setting the positioning of the container view using autolayout, whereby it is always touching the top, left and right of the uiviewcontroller it is within and always 50px from the bottom due to a UIButton being there.

The UITableViewController has a larger content size than the height of the container view, so one would expect you to be able to scroll the tableview from the container view.

But for some reason I cannot get it to work, when you initially load the UIViewController the scroll indicator appears and then hides and it won't let you scroll the tableview. How would I solve this?

(It has previously worked for me, I just can't remember what I did.)

Comment: As far as i remember UITableViewController should scroll only if his content size is bigger than his OWN size. U can always debug it in Interface builder when u RUN the app(also pay attention to scroolEnabled property.).

Comment: can you show how you are embedding this UITableViewController in the other view controller?

Comment: It's literally being embedded through a storyboard embed segue. The UIViewController the container view is in, the container view itself and the UITableViewController that is embedded in the container view are all created using storyboards too.